# JS UTF-8 Decoding Issues: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the "0o" prefix instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, utf-8

I've been banging my head off a wall trying to get this work, any help appreciated.

I essentially have a string that might looks like this "jas\303\241nek" and I want to convert it to a string that looks like this "jasánek". I've used [this site]https://mothereff.in/utf-8 which successfully managed to decode the string to the desired output, and wanted to integrate it into my site. This site uses a npm package [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) which I've been trying to get working. It appeared that writing code like this wasn't sufficient in making the translation:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8')
let string = "jas\303\241nek"
let translation = utf8.decode(string);
console.log(translation)
```

Upon seeing this only returned the original string I realised the functionality wasn't what I assumed so I dug into the [code for the initial translation site](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/mothereff.in/blob/master/utf-8/eff.js#L45) and saw it uses this syntax:

```
utf8.decode(eval('\'' + encoded.value + '\''));
```

So I tried implementing some variation of this like this:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8')
let string = "jas\303\241nek"
let translation = utf8.decode(eval('\'' + string + '\'');
console.log(translation)
```

Which returns an error that I don't understand:

```
SyntaxError: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the "0o" prefix instead
```

And now I'm stuck. Any suggestions for how I might be able to resolve this problem?

Comment: "*I essentially have a string that might looks like this `"jas\303\241nek"`*" - where does that come from? Fix the code that produces this string in the first place.

Comment: string comes from an API call response so I cant manipulate the source data

Comment: Does that API use the backslash escaping? Or does it just use a weird encoding (and does not properly declare that in its content-type headers)? You should either fix your code (we can help if you post it) or report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue ended up being trying to do the utf8 translations on the frontend with the library. I discovered this when trying to console.log the sample string and getting the string back instead of the value of the symbols.

To fix this I did the utf8 translations on the express server that sent it to the frontend and this resolved the problem.

Thanks all for the suggestions.